# Custom page with form

Tags: forms, 8, blocks

i am new to drupal i want to make custom page with form , i googled and was able to built custom form using guide at [Link](http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/step-by-step-method-to-create-a-custom-form-in-drupal-8)

but i need form as part of my page content not just form so basically i need custom page with form ,please guide me with this .

Have i to recode it or can use buildForm at certain place in my html, please help me with suitable link or guide

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a route, and a controller that builds the response on that route - in your case a form.